# RSS audio enclosures have length of zero (podcast duration is missing)

Tags: media, rss, audio, podcasting

I have had success at creating an RSS feed with enclosures containing episodes of my podcast by simply creating a post and inserting an mp3 file from my media library into it via the robust `Add Media` functionality of the post editor. However, I have found that the RSS feed created from these posts includes an enclosure for each mp3 file with its length attribute set to zero:

```
<enclosure url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/myfile.mp3" length="0" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

How can I set the length attribute of the enclosure so that it is accurate?

I am not interested in changing the format of my posts, so any plugin-based solution should not require a significantly different workflow when posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enclosure tag will implement via the function [`rss_enclosure`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rss_enclosure/). This function has the filter hook `rss_enclosure`. So you can change the result via this hook.

[Here is a longer post](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/extending-the-default-wordpress-rss-feed--wp-27935) about the how-to for audio files, this should help you.

Comment: Thank so much! It turns out the length attribute actually holds the file size in bytes. Duration goes inside the `<itunes:duration>` element. I managed to use the guide found in the link you provided, combined with the `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` function to get the duration from the file itself. In the guide, they simply use one of the audio file's meta fields to manually set the length.